Alerts mail are not coming from alert manager even after configured it correctly


alertmanager.yml


route:
    group_by: Mail alert
    receiver: myemail@gmail.com

receivers:
    - name: Mail alert
      email_config:
       - to: myemail@gmail.com
         from: testsmtp@gmail.com
         smarthost: xxxxxx:xx
         auth_username: testsmtp@gmail.com
         auth_password: xxxxxxxxx



In prometheus, Alert manager is configured, alerts are firing but unable to receive emails through SMTP. Getting connection refused issue for localhost. I didn't use any localhost in my configuration and also getting issue with webhook.
Below is the error:
ts=2024-10-03T10:00:26.318Z caller=notify.go:848 level=warn component=dispatcher receiver=web.hook integration=webhook[0] aggrGroup="{}:{alertname=\"test Down\"}" msg="Notify attempt failed, will retry later" attempts=1 err="Post \"<redacted>\": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5001: connect: connection refused" 

I tried configuring SMTP to get alert mails through alert manager in prometheus but not receiving the emails.
